# Iptables bang position

Tags: linux, iptables

I am trying to set up this rule :

```
 iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -s ! 10.111.11.0/24 --dport ssh --syn -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

but it doesnt work. When i change place of !

```
 iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp ! -s 10.111.11.0/24 --dport ssh --syn -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

its ok but i am not sure is it working correctly. In every tut on net "!" is between -s and ip not in front of it.

Comment: Could you clarify "*it doesn't work*"?  And you are escaping that `!`, aren't you?

Comment: I must say, iptables is extremely powerful, but it's command line interface crap.  FreeBSD's ipf is significantly easier to understand in my opinion although I haven't used it in a long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second example is correct.

The first example is an old and deprecated way of writing such rules; current versions of iptables will print a warning, or refuse the rule entirely, if you use it.

Old tutorials on the Internet, of course, have old information.